# Git how to delete all stashes not containing a specific name

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree

EG. I have many stashes, but one named "my special stash" I want to keep.

Something like `git stash clear !"my special stash"` would be nice, thanks for help.

Answer (score 1):

Find out your favorite stash ref that you want to keep, `stash@{3}` for example.

```
#create a tag for the favorite stash ref
git tag mystash stash@{3}
#clear all stash refs
git stash clear
#reproduce the favorite stash 
git reset mystash
git stash
#clear the tag
git tag -d mystash
```

Comment: Is this a good idea? `git reset` is going to whack on the current branch. You can fix it again later with another `git reset`, perhaps. A better idea might be to use `git stash store` to re-create the stash from the temporary tag.

Comment: @torek Mind adding the commands? not sure how they would be different using store, thanks friend.

Comment: @torek thanks. I didn't know about `git stash restore`.

Comment: @Andrew: Assuming the rest of the answer above, `git stash store [-m message] mystash` would replace `git reset mystash; git stash`. I have not tested this.